# Uncaught TypeError:c._shady_getRootNode is not a function

Tags: html, angular, web-component, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jspdf library to convert html to pdf using angular 8. Jspdf version am using is 2.3.0. I am able to create blob and open as PDF in new window but I am getting below console errors too.

```
Uncaught TypeError: c.__shady_getRootNode is not a function

    at HTMLHtmlElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLBodyElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLDivElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLDivElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLDivElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLDivElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLDivElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at HTMLElement.getRootNode (webcomponents-sd.js:70)

    at cc (webcomponents-sd.js:98)
```

Any solution to fix this would be helpful.